# Azure cache write implementation approaches - when to use which

Tags: caching, azure

I used to call the `Put(Key, Value)` method to set data in Azure cache. I later learnt that this method could lead to race conditions during writes and introduced the following code for setting data into cache.

```
                    try
                    {
                        if (GetData(key) == null)
                        {
                            _cache.Add(key, "--dummy--");
                        }

                        DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle;
                        TimeSpan lockTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                        _cache.GetAndLock(key, lockTimeout, out lockHandle);

                        if (ttlInMinutes == 0)
                        {
                            _cache.PutAndUnlock(key, value, lockHandle);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TimeSpan ttl = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(ttlInMinutes);
                            _cache.PutAndUnlock(key, value, lockHandle, ttl);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {}
```

This involves two IOs as against one in the previous call. Is this locking really needed in application code? Is cache consistency not taken care of by Azure's caching framework? What is the standard way of managing cache writes in Azure? When to use Put and when PutAndUnlock?